# build failure Jenkins+Maven+SVN

Tags: maven, jenkins, svn

Started by user xxx
Building in workspace C:\Users\Vinay.jenkins\workspace\Orbit App Automation
Updating https://polarisdev.svn.cloudforge.com/qaautomation at revision '2017-12-01T11:04:13.362 +0530'
Using sole credentials xxxx/****** in realm ‘https://polarisdev.svn.cloudforge.com:443 CloudForge login’
At revision 5

No changes for https://polarisdev.svn.cloudforge.com/qaautomation since the previous build
[qaautomation] $ cmd.exe /C "D:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\mvn.cmd -f pom.xml '"-Dmaven.repo.local=C:\Users\Vinay.jenkins\workspace\Orbit App Automation.repository"' clean install && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
POM file pom.xml specified the -f/--file command-line argument does not exist 
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: vinaya.mopidi@orbitanalytics.com
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: i am getting build failure error message and i have configured the project in Jenkins , SVN and maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now ,earlier i have given incorrectly Repository URL (svn url) now given up to svn work space

Correct : https://xxxx.svn.xxx.com/qaautomation/xxxAutomation
InCorrect : https://xxxx.svn.xxx.com/qaautomation

Answer (score 0):

Build step '**Invoke top-level Maven targets**' marked build as failure because you entered your shell script in maven goals and options input field.

You command seems to be a free style windows command script .

```
cmd.exe /C "D:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\mvn.cmd -f pom.xml '"-Dmaven.repo.local=C:\Users\Vinay.jenkins\workspace\Orbit App Automation.repository"' clean install && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
```

Select the **execute windows batch command** radio button in the build step.